# How to make editable value in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a project. I work on json file. I got a sort in python. This is TreeView and I want to make changes to the TreeView. How do i editable it every cell.

```
import json
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ViewTree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, value):

        super().__init__()
        def fill_item(item, value):
            def new_item(parent, text, val=None):
                child = QTreeWidgetItem([text])
                fill_item(child, val)
                parent.addChild(child)
                child.setExpanded(True)
            if value is None: return
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                for key, val in sorted(value.items()):
                    new_item(item, str(key), val)
            elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                for val in value:
                    text = (str(val) if not isinstance(val, (dict, list, tuple))
                            else '[%s]' % type(val).__name__)
                    new_item(item, text, val)
            else:
                new_item(item, str(value))

        fill_item(self.invisibleRootItem(), value)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])


    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    json_file=open(fname[0],"r")
    file=json.load(json_file)


    window = ViewTree(file)
    window.setGeometry(300, 100, 900, 600)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable the [`Qt::ItemIsEditable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) flag:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# ...

child = QTreeWidgetItem([text])
child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```